Oracle Sql plan baseline already fixed but v$sql.SQL_PLAN_BASELINE still null
There're two different plan for one specific SQL_ID. Because of the cost, I prefer one of those plan.
I'm trying to use plan baseline and fixed the better one but fail.
My steps:

load plans from cursor to plan baseline

DBMS_SPM.LOAD_PLANS_FROM_CURSOR_CACHE(sql_id => ?) 

After this, I can check dba_sql_plan_baselines do have two plan of the sql_id.
Then find the one I need by DISPLAY_SQL_PLAN_BASELINE().

fixed the one I'd think it's better

DBMS_SPM.alter_sql_plan_baseline(
sql_handle      => ?,
    plan_name       => ?,
    attribute_name  => 'fixed',
    attribute_value => 'YES'

After this, column FIXED in dba_sql_planbaselines change to 'YES'. Both ENABLED & ACCEPTED are 'YES'.
I also alter the other plan ENABLED to 'NO'.
But the sql_id in v$sql.sql_plan_baseline is still null and in v$active_session_history, it still using two different plan.
Is any setting missing?
